# chrome always open these type of links in associated app checkbox is missing in selenium

Tags: selenium, registry

When I opened selenium with python, I can't find the always open these kinds of links with associated app checkbox anymore.
People suggested me to use the registry editor to enable it and yes it worked but when I opened the selenium again with my python script it doesn't work! As in don't work I mean the checkbox is displayed but selenium doesn't remember it anymore. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooo , i think i know what your problem is. The reason why selenium doesn't remember your changed settings was because you don't use the same chrome profile in your python script. Try this:

````
options = Options()
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=path\to\your\chrome\profile')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'path\to\your\chromedriver.exe', options=options)```
If you don't know how to check your profile, go to your webbrowser and type chrome://version and scroll until you can find the profile path subheading! Cheers, and good luck.
````

Comment: and for those of you that would like to know the registry editor method to enable the checkbox, check this link out https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/eebchb/always_open_these_types_of_links_in_the/